# junit integration with php based application

Tags: java, php, unit-testing, junit

I am exploring [junit](http://www.junit.org/) for unit testing. I have seen that it is java based. I have explored it and I have still some questions

1. Can I integrate junit with php based applications for unit testing?
2. Test cases will only be written in java? Can I write test cases in PHP using junit?

I have explored tutorials and I have seen all test cases are written in Java. But I have someone who is saying it can be done. So any guide will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I am using selenium 2 (webdriver) to auto test php project. I am using PHP binding (phpunit), but I need to write some functions like isElementPresent by myself. If I can use java binding, then I will have more api supporting via using junit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit is a Java unit testing framework. It's meant to unit-test java-classes by means of tests written in Java that are highly coupled to the implementation they are testing. Not sure what the "someone" you have means when he/she says it can be used to unit-test PHP. Maybe you are looking for [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/).